# How to export classes from AssemblyScript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, assemblyscript

I am trying to port my simple collision detection library from JavaScript to WebAssembly for speed. After looking up languages that compile to WASM, AssemblyScript seemed to be perfect as I only needed to add types to my JS file. The whole library is a `Class` and after adding types I tried to compile it but it does not compile properly. For example, compiling this using command `npx asc path/to/main.ts -o wasm.wasm --exportRuntime -t wasm.wat --bindings esm`:

```js
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Successful!');
    }
};
```

Resulted in this error:

```
WARNING AS235: Only variables, functions and enums become WebAssembly module exports.

 export class Test {
              ~~~~
 in main.ts(1,14)
```

After seeing the error I tried to fix it by doing:

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Successful!');
    }
};

export function getTest(): Test {
    return Test;
};
```

But that resulted in another error:

```
ERROR AS234: Expression does not compile to a value at runtime.

     return Test;
            ~~~~
 in main.ts(8,12)

FAILURE 1 compile error(s)
```

So I tried to do this:

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Successful!');
    }
};

export function getTest(): Test {
    return new Test();
};
```

That compiled successfully and after calling `getTest` from JavaScript I got an output `Successful!` in the console but it did not return the initiated class, instead I got this: `[Number (Internref): 18624]`.

So I serched on the internet for solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543434/exporting-classes-from-webassembly-to-javascript-with-assemblyscript). But the accepted solution there is to use [AssemblyScript Loader](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/tree/main/lib/loader), which is deprecated. I also know about [as-bind](https://github.com/torch2424/as-bind) but it states that it wraps around AssemblyScript Loader so, indirectly, it is also deprecated. So how can I export classes from AssemblyScript?

Comment: You don't export classes, simple as that. You can only export functions that will call methods on an instance passed to them.

Comment: @Bergi I suppose I can split my class into an object containing all the properties, and all the methods as independent functions that modify and use the values in the object. But I need to run multiple instances of the library so I think I will handle raw calculations in WASM and a JS class over it for other things. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there currently is no way to export classes.
However, you can call methods on a class from JavaScript or call a get or set method to modify data.
I believe it is planned to have functions named like
`Vec3#constructor`
`Vec3#magnitude`
ect..

[Exporting classes from WebAssembly to JavaScript with Assemblyscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543434/exporting-classes-from-webassembly-to-javascript-with-assemblyscript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I gave up on trying to export classes from AssemblyScript. I now just handle raw calculations in AssemblyScript and a wrapper class in JS. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: Honestly, I would do the same in practice.

Comment: I am trying to understand the use case for AssemblyScript, as there are no classes, no interfaces, no closures, no destructuring...?

Answer (score 0):

A short update regarding this question:

I also tried this using AssemblyScript 0.27.22 and ran into the same issue. According to the manual (https://www.assemblyscript.org/compiler.html#host-bindings) complex objects are returned as reference (pointer) while for simple objects it is possible to return a copy of them.

```js
class Person {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

export function createPerson(): Person {
  return {firstname: 'AFirstName', lastname: 'ALastName'};
}
```

I used this example in my Typescript file and logged the result in my JS/HTML file, it should look like this: "Generate person:  {firstname: 'AFirstName', lastname: 'ALastName'}"

While this is still not perfect it is a step to a better type/object support.